# How to use localStorage to remain disable an input even if refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I want to do is if i click `No` on the radio button it will disable even if i refreshed or closed the browser and reopen it again it still disable until i click `Yes` button the disable will be gone.

How to do it using localStorage?

testing link: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/156/

html:

```
<input type="radio" name="employed" id="employed_v1" value="Yes" required="required" /> Yes<br />
<input type="radio" name="employed" id="employed_v0" value="No" required="required" /> No <br>

<input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#test').on("keyup change", function () {
       debugger;
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val())
    });


    $('#test').each(function (ind, val) {
            debugger;

         $(val).val(localStorage.getItem($(val).attr("id")))

    });

    $('#employed_v1, #employed_v0').on("change", function () {
        localStorage.setItem('employed', $(this).attr("id"))
    });

    $('#' + localStorage.getItem('employed')).attr('checked', true);

$('[id="employed_v0"]').on('click', function(){
        $('#test').val('');
        localStorage.removeItem('test');
        $('#test').prop('disabled', true);        
     });
$('[id="employed_v1"]').on('click', function(){
        $('#test').prop('disabled', false);
     });

});
```

Comment: @CDspace it has no answer that im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, check the demo, change radio button and enter some text in textbox and run jsfiddle again it will remain in same state.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/LgA2m/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("itmEmployee") == "Yes")
        $("#employed_v1").prop("checked", true);
    else
        $("#employed_v0").prop("checked", true);

    if(localStorage.getItem("itmEmployee") == "Yes")
        $("#test").prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $("#test").prop("disabled", true);

    $("#test").val(localStorage.getItem("itmTest"));

    $("[name=employed]").on("change", function(){
        localStorage.setItem("itmEmployee", $(this).val());

        if($(this).val() == "Yes")
            $("#test").prop("disabled", false);
        else
            $("#test").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $("#test").on("change", function(){
        localStorage.setItem("itmTest", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: i need it disable if if No button is clicked

Comment: @user3763580 code updated pl check

Comment: where did u get this itmEmployee and itmTest?

Comment: @user3763580 its a key to store in HTML5 localStorage